# How to make eclipse auto-complete search be case-sensitive?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

On Eclipse 2019-09 there is a very annoying "feature" which finds the wrong method when you are typing its name. The image below speaks for itself.

When I type "*rem*", it selects has**Rem**aining() and not **rem**aining(). Also when I type "*rem*", of course **rem**aining() should appear first and before should_**rem**anage(). **Is it possible to fix that?**

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX6Y9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content assist` and you will find an option that let you select between `relevance` and `alphabetically`.
Also checkbox allow you to select camelcase matches '`show camel case matches`' -
tune these properties to get expected results..